# Multiple delimiters with scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to read a multi-line file. The contents are in the following format: `( 0, 250, 6.4545, 250 )`
I have tried to use the use.Delimiter() function like

```
r = new FileInputStream ("Z:\\RTS\\HW2\\input.txt");
Scanner src = new Scanner(r);
src.useDelimiter("\\{(\\s),\\}+");
if(r!= null)
{
  i=0;
  while (src.hasNext()) 
  {
    System.out.println(src.nextInt()); // Line 84
    if(src.hasNext())
      a = (double)src.nextInt();
    if(src.hasNext())
    {
      b = (double)src.nextInt();
      period[i] = (int)b;
    }
    if(src.hasNext())
    {
      c = src.nextDouble();
      exTime[i] = c;
    }
    if(src.hasNext())
      d = src.nextDouble();
      src.nextLine();
      i++;
    }
  }
```

I am getting the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at rm.rmcalc.main(rmcalc.java:84)
```

I reckon the mismatch is probably because the delimiters are not recognized by the scanner function. Could someone tell me if I'm erring in declaring the delimiters ?

Comment: I am not sure if I quite follow that. The fields with the floating point value (6.4545) are read using nextDouble. That shouldn't throw a mismatch, should it ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of problems here, not the least of which is that your regex is totally garbled.

```
\{(\s),\}+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2lDCFmeUrUzc5GaL)

You're matching a literal `{`, followed by a space and a comma, then another one or more literal `}`s.  If you're trying to split on commas, you generally simply need:

```
\s*,\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1HqsWqVS80zSTH1Y)

(Sidenote, Debuggex is great, but it's not Java-specific - I really like [RegexPlanet's tool](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) for playing with Java patterns.)

---

Once you've fixed your delimiter though, you've still got problems.  You're not using Scanner correctly at all.  Take a look at the [Java Tutorial on Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) first.  At a minimum, you need to pair your `.hasNext*()` calls with your `.next*()` calls, i.e. call `hasNextInt()` before calling `.nextInt()`.  But you also are doing a bunch of convoluted conditional processing that will fail in strange ways for malformed data.

Rather than walking you through cleaning this up, let me suggest a different pattern.  Often, when people want to read from a file, they use two separate Scanners.  One uses the default delimiter and they simply call `.nextLine()` repeatedly on it.  Then, they pass that line into a second Scanner with a custom delimiter, and extract the individual components line by line.  This lets you easily test parsing a single line, so you can debug your line-parsing behavior separately from your file-reading behavior.